# Is smn theorem the same concept as currying?

Tags: computability

I am studying the s-m-n theorem and the concept reminded me of currying.

From wikipedia article about [s-m-n theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smn_theorem):

> the theorem says that for a given programming language and positive integers m and n, there exists a particular algorithm that accepts as input the source code of a program with m + n free variables, together with m values. This algorithm generates source code that effectively substitutes the values for the first m free variables, leaving the rest of the variables free.

From an article about [currying](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~taha/teaching/05F/210/news/2005_10_26.htm):

> Intuitively, currying says "if you fix some arguments, you get a function of the remaining arguments"

Seems like the same idea to me. The only reason why I am unsure is that the materials I came across on s-m-n don't mention currying (and vice versa), so I wanted to consult it to make sure I actually get it.

Comment: Indeed. Some computability proofs have a lambdish flavor. The s-m-n theorem, very roughly, allows to pretend that indexes of recursive functions are lambda terms, so that given $\phi_i(-,-)$ we can craft the informal $g(x) = \#\lambda y. \phi_i(x,y)$ and claim that $g$ is primitive recursive. Even the second recursion theorem proof (which exploits s-m-n) is Church's fixed point combinator in disguise, hidden behind $s()$ uses. The key point here is that even if the enumeration $\phi_i$ is defined enumerating, say, TMs (or Java, or ...) we can _still_ pretend we have lambdas!

Comment: Well, s-m-n makes an existential statement while the existence of a curried function *provides* the "compiler". But the idea is the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is the same thing.

Currying is a concept from $\lambda$-calculus. It is a transformation between $A \times B \to C$ and $A \to (B \to C)$. Think of this as "if we have a function of two arguments of types $A$ and $B$, then we may fix the first argument (of type $A$), and we will get a function of the remaining argument (of type $B$)". In fact, this transformation is an isomorphism. This is made mathematically precise by mathematical models of (typed) $\lambda$-calculus, which are [cartesian closed categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category).

There is a category of numbered sets. A numbered set is a pair $(A, \nu_A)$ where $A$ is a set and $\nu_A : \mathbb{N} \to A$ is a *partial* surjection, i.e., a map from numbers onto $A$, which may also be undefined. If $\nu_A(n) = x$ then we say that $n$ is a *code* of $x$. In computability theory there are many examples. Whenever we encode some information with a number we get a numbered set. For instance, there is a standard numbering $\varphi$ of partial computable functions, so that $\varphi_n(k)$ is the number computed by the partial computable function encoded by $n$ when applied to $k$. (The result may be undefined.)

A morphism of numbered sets is a *realized map* $f : (A, \nu_A) \to (B, \nu_B)$, which means that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(\nu_A(k)) = \nu_B(\varphi_n(k))$ for all $k$ in the domain of $\nu_A$. This looks complicated, but all it says is that $\varphi_n$ does to codes what $f$ does to elements. It is the mathematical way of saying that "program $\phi_n$ implements function $f$".

Here is the punchline: the category of numbered sets is cartesian closed. We may therefore interpret the typed $\lambda$-calulus in it, and ask what program implements the currying operation. The answer is: the program given by the s-m-n theorem.

Comment: Interesting. Is that category closely related to $PER(A)$? $\nu_A$ seems to induce a PER.

Comment: Yes, the two categories are equivalent, and the third equivalent version is that of *modest sets* (lookup "modest sets and assemblies").